# RendererColorChange and Transform.position doesn't work

Tags: unity, c#

```
    void LeftPartFalls()
{
    if (LeftPartMat)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Mathf.Min(5, FirstLine.Length); i++)        // COLOR CHANGE
        {
            Debug.Log(i);
            FirstLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            SecondLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            ThirdLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            FourthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            FiftLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            SixthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            SeventhLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            EighthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            NinthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            TenthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
        }
    }
    if (!LeftPartMat)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Mathf.Min(5, FirstLine.Length); i++)        // COLOR CHANGE
        {
            FirstLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
            SecondLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
            ThirdLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
            FourthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
            FiftLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
            SixthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
            SeventhLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
            EighthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
            NinthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
            TenthLine[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(162f / 255f, 172f / 255f, 186f / 255f, 1f);
        }
    }

    if (LeftPartFall)       // FALL DOWN
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Mathf.Min(5, FirstLine.Length); i++)
        {
            FirstLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(FirstLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(FirstLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, FirstLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            SecondLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(SecondLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(SecondLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, SecondLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            ThirdLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(ThirdLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(ThirdLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, ThirdLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            FourthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(FourthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(FourthLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, FourthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            FiftLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(FiftLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(FiftLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, FiftLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            SixthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(SixthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(SixthLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, SixthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            SeventhLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(SeventhLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(SeventhLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, SeventhLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            EighthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(EighthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(EighthLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, EighthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            NinthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(NinthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(NinthLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, NinthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            TenthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(TenthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(TenthLine[i].transform.position.x, -4f, TenthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
        }
    }
    if (!LeftPartFall)      // RISE UP
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Mathf.Min(5, FirstLine.Length); i++)
        {
            FirstLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(FirstLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(FirstLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, FirstLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            SecondLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(SecondLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(SecondLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, SecondLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            ThirdLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(ThirdLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(ThirdLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, ThirdLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            FourthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(FourthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(FourthLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, FourthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            FiftLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(FiftLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(FiftLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, FiftLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            SixthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(SixthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(SixthLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, SixthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            SeventhLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(SeventhLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(SeventhLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, SeventhLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            EighthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(EighthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(EighthLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, EighthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            NinthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(NinthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(NinthLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, NinthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
            TenthLine[i].gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(TenthLine[i].transform.position, new Vector3(TenthLine[i].transform.position.x, 0f, TenthLine[i].transform.position.z), t);
        }
    }
}
private IEnumerator enumerator(float waitTime)
{
    while (true)
    {
        LeftPartMat = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

        LeftPartFall = true;

        t = 0f;
        t += Time.deltaTime / 0.7f;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        LeftPartFall = false;
        LeftPartMat = false;           
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    }
}
```

> WaitTime is 4f

1. Color doesn't changes
2. The result i want is; [image: Result i want]
   The result i get; [image: Result i get]

> By the way this script was working last day, i tested it several times and save&closed it, other day i changed nothing and just open the client and test it again and noticed it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem, if you're having the some issue:

```
public Vector2Int size = new Vector2Int(10, 10);
public float spacing = 1f;
public MeshRenderer tilePrefab;
MeshRenderer[,] tiles;

public Material fallingMaterial;
public Material risingMaterial;
public float fallSeconds = 3f;
public float fallHeight = -4f;
public float riseSeconds = 4f;

void Awake()
{
    CreateFloor();
    StartCoroutine(AnimationLoop(3f));
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -20);
}

void CreateFloor()
{
    // Define our tiles array in the appropriate size.
    tiles = new MeshRenderer[size.x, size.y];

    // Spawn the floor centered around this object's position.
    Vector3 origin = transform.position + new Vector3(size.x, 0, size.y) * -0.5f * spacing;

    // For each row, and each column, instantiate a tile.
    for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
        {
            tiles[x, y] = Instantiate<MeshRenderer>(tilePrefab, new Vector3(x, 0, y) * spacing + origin, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
        {
            tiles[x, y].gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("GroundLayer");
        }
    }
}

void SelectLeftHalf(List<MeshRenderer> pattern)
{
    Debug.Log("SelectLeftHalf");
    pattern.Clear();
    for (int x = 0; x < size.x / 2; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
        {
            pattern.Add(tiles[x, y]);
        }
    }
}

void ChangeAllMaterials(List<MeshRenderer> pattern, Material material)
{
    foreach (var renderer in pattern)
        renderer.sharedMaterial = material;
}

IEnumerator SlideAllBlocks(List<MeshRenderer> pattern, float startHeight, float endHeight, float duration)
{
    float progress = 0f;
    while (progress < 1f)
    {
        progress = Mathf.Clamp01(progress + Time.deltaTime / duration);

        // Compute a height to move to, with an ease-out curve.
        float height = Mathf.Lerp(startHeight, endHeight, 1 - (1 - progress) * (1 - progress));

        // Set all blocks in the pattern to this height.
        foreach (var renderer in pattern)
        {
            var position = renderer.transform.position;
            position.y = height;
            renderer.transform.position = position;
        }

        // Wait one frame, then resume.
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator AnimationLoop(float moveSeconds)
{
    // Prep our variable for tracking the pattern of tiles we're acting on.
    // Since this is a local variable, we can control exactly who gets to act on it,
    // so anything that changes the pattern should be easy to track down.
    var pattern = new List<MeshRenderer>();

    while (true)
    {
        // Each cycle, select a randomly-chosen pattern of blocks.
        int selection = Random.Range(1, 2);

        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1: SelectLeftHalf(pattern); break;
        }

        // Change the material of all blocks in this pattern.
        ChangeAllMaterials(pattern, fallingMaterial);

        // Wait before we start to fall.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(moveSeconds);

        // Chain control to our sliding method until the fall is complete.
        yield return SlideAllBlocks(pattern, 0f, fallHeight, fallSeconds);

        // Done falling. Reset the materials and rise back up.
        ChangeAllMaterials(pattern, risingMaterial);

        // Chain control to our sliding method until the fall is complete.
        yield return SlideAllBlocks(pattern, fallHeight, 0f, riseSeconds);

        // Everything has risen and reset. Now adjust our moveSeconds for next cycle:
        if (moveSeconds >= 1.3f)
        {
            moveSeconds -= 0.7f;
        }
        else if (moveSeconds <= 1.3f)
        {
            moveSeconds = Mathf.Max(moveSeconds - 0.6f, 0.7f);
        }

        // Wait before starting the next cycle & choosing a new pattern.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(moveSeconds);
    }
}
```

It can be look complicated at the first look but trust me it's simple.

**If you are having a problem with understanding**, check this [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/172065/126000), at that post DmGregory has a great answer about it.